# Apply function or Loop in R: Not numerical, returning NA

Tags: r, resampling

I am working with a resampling procedure in R (just like a bootstrap). I have a matrix of response/explanatory variables and would like to make 999 samples of this matrix to calculate for each statistic I am working their mean, sd and confidence interval. So, I wrote a function to calculate and to return a list:

```
mydata <- data.frame(a=rnorm(20, 1, 1), b = rnorm(20,1,1))

myfun <- function(data, n){
  sample <- data[sample(n, replace = T),]
  model1 <- lm(sample[,1]~sample[,2])
  return(list(model1[[1]][[1]], model1[[1]][[2]]))
}

result <- as.numeric()
result <- replicate(99, myfun(mydata, 10))
```

Then, I have a matrix as my output in which the rows are the statistics and the columns are the samplings (nrow = 2 and ncol = 99). I need the mean and sd for each row, but when I try to use the apply function or even a loop the following message shows up:

> In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
>         argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Moreover:

```
is.numeric(result)
[1] FALSE
```

I found it strange, because I never had such problem with similar procedures.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could this be because you are returning a `list`? If you run `is.numeric(result[[1]])`, you do get the `TRUE` you would expect.

Comment: Another way is to return a vector, not a list: `return(c(model1[[1]][[1]], model1[[1]][[2]]))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following:

```
myfun <- function(dat, n){
  dat1 <- dat[sample(n, replace = T),]
  model1 <- lm(dat1[,1] ~ dat1[,2])
  return(coef(model1))
  }

replicate(99, myfun(mydata, 10))
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is the 'result' is a `list` of 198 elements with dimension attributes.  We need to `unlist` the 'result' and provide the dimension attributes

```
result1 <- `dim<-`(unlist(result), dim(result))
```

and then use the `apply`

Answer (score 0):

Just replace list() by c() in your myfun() function

```
mydata <- data.frame(a=rnorm(20, 1, 1), b = rnorm(20,1,1))

myfun <- function(data, n){
  sample <- data[sample(n, replace = T),]
  model1 <- lm(sample[,1]~sample[,2])
  return(c(model1[[1]][[1]], model1[[1]][[2]]))
}

result <- as.numeric()
result <- replicate(99, myfun(mydata, 10))

apply(result, FUN=mean, 1)
apply(result, FUN=sd, 1)
```

Comment: As you pointed out, coef() will return the appropriate format of data and is the efficient way to solve this issue. Nevertheless, for this example showing explicitly the expected data format with c() might be more didactic and help generalisation !

Comment: You are right too. I was trying to apply a loop over a list, but the correct is to replace by c() to create a vector. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
mydata <- data.frame(a=rnorm(20, 1, 1), b = rnorm(20,1,1))

myfun <- function(data, n){
  sample <- data[sample(n, replace = T),]
  model1 <- lm(sample[,1]~sample[,2])
  return(data.frame(v1 = model1[[1]][[1]], v2 = model1[[1]][[2]]))
}

result <- do.call("rbind",(replicate(99, myfun(mydata, 10), simplify = FALSE)))
```